.NET 8 - How to use Dependency Injection to Inject two MongoDB Clients
How do I inject two MongoDB clients with Dependency Injection (.NET 8)? I have a scenario where I need to read from Db1/collection1 and then save something to Db2/collection2. In my Startup, I have the following but not sure how to inject a second IMongoClient (both have different connection strings.)
services.AddSingleton<IMongoClient>x => new
    MongoClient(My_Server_Connection1));

services.AddSingleton<IMongoClient>x => new
    MongoClient(My_Server_Connection2));

I would like to be able to do something like this in my DataStore constructor.
Db DataStore 1:
public DataStore1(IMongoClient clientWithConStr1, IMongoClient clientWithConStr2)
{
    database1 = clientWithConStr1.GetDatabase(DatabaseName1);
    database2 = clientWithConStr2.GetDatabase(DatabaseName1);
}


@ChristophLütjen can you elaborate a bit more on that please as im not following

@O'NeilTomlinson He means that you have to have 2 different interfaces which is a bad practice.
Lookup in google "Factory" pattern

Do the two clients need different connection strings/settings or are those the same?

For your scenario to handle multiple MongoClients with different connection strings, it is better to implement a factory to select the MongoClient (provider) by type.

An interface and class provider to initiate and retrive the MongoClient by type.

public interface IMongoClientProvider
{
    public int Type { get; }

    public IMongoClient GetMongoClient();
}

public class MongoClientProvider : IMongoClientProvider
{
    public int Type { get; init; }
    private readonly IMongoClient _client;

    public MongoClientProvider(int type, string connectionString)
    {
        Type = type;
        _client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
    }

    public IMongoClient GetMongoClient()
    {
        return _client;
    }
}


A factory to select the MongoClientProvider by type`.

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class MongoClientFactory
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IMongoClientProvider> _providers;

    public MongoClientFactory(IEnumerable<IMongoClientProvider> providers)
    {
        _providers = providers;
    }

    public MongoClient GetMongoClient(int type)
    {
        var provider = _providers.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Type == type);
        if (provider == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Unsupported type for provider.");
        }

        return provider.GetMongoClient();
    }
}


Register the MongoClientProvider and MongoClientFactory into DI container.

services.AddSingleton<IMongoClientProvider>(new MongoClientProvider(1, My_Server_Connection));
services.AddSingleton<IMongoClientProvider>(new MongoClientProvider(2, My_Server_Connection2));

services.AddSingleton<MongoClientFactory>();


In the DataStore class, get the MongoClientFactory from the DI and retrieve the MongoClient instance by type.

public class DataStore1
{
    private readonly IMongoDatabase database;
    private readonly string databaseName = "DatabaseName1";
    
    public DataStore1(MongoClientFactory factory)
    {
        var client = factory.GetMongoClient(1);
        database = client.GetDatabase(databaseName);
    }
}

public class DataStore2
{
    private readonly IMongoDatabase database;
    private readonly string databaseName = "DatabaseName2";
    
    public DataStore2(MongoClientFactory factory)
    {
        var client = factory.GetMongoClient(2);
        database = client.GetDatabase(databaseName);
    }
}


Demo @ .NET Fiddle

This worked. Thanks very much. I'll mark as the Answer

You can achieve this easily through keyed service registrations, a new feature released with .NET 8.
This allows you to register a service and also provide a key. You also specify the key where you want to inject the instance. This way, you do not have to create marker interfaces but can solely rely on .NET dependency injection.
The following sample registers two MongoClient instances as singleton, one with a key of "MongoClientA" and another with a key of "MongoClientB". This sample only sets a different application name to show that the instances are injected correctly; in production code, you'd likely have different connection strings that you read from configuration.
Both instances are injected into the Datastore instance; the use of the FromKeyedServices attribute allows the IoC container to discern between the registrations:
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using MongoDB.Driver;

var prov = new ServiceCollection()
    .AddKeyedSingleton<IMongoClient>(
    Constants.MongoClientA,
    (prov, key) =>
    {
        var settings = MongoClientSettings.FromConnectionString("mongodb://localhost:27017");
        settings.ApplicationName = "A";
        return new MongoClient(settings);
    })
    .AddKeyedSingleton<IMongoClient>(
    Constants.MongoClientB,
    (prov, key) =>
    {
        var settings = MongoClientSettings.FromConnectionString("mongodb://localhost:27017");
        settings.ApplicationName = "B";
        return new MongoClient(settings);
    })
    .AddSingleton<DataStore>()
    .BuildServiceProvider();

var ds = prov.GetRequiredService<DataStore>();

public class Constants
{
    public const string MongoClientA = "MongoClientA";
    public const string MongoClientB = "MongoClientB";
}

public class DataStore
{
    private readonly IMongoClient _clientA;
    private readonly IMongoClient _clientB;

    public DataStore(
        [FromKeyedServices(Constants.MongoClientA)] IMongoClient clientA, 
        [FromKeyedServices(Constants.MongoClientB)] IMongoClient clientB)
    {
        _clientA = clientA;
        _clientB = clientB;
        Console.WriteLine("ApplicationName A = " + clientA.Settings.ApplicationName);
        Console.WriteLine("ApplicationName B = " + clientB.Settings.ApplicationName);
    }
}

When running the sample, the following text is written to the console:

ApplicationName A = A
ApplicationName B = B

